# dynamically adding activeX button in a loop not working in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop in which I am adding ActiveX buttons in a particular sheet. But no matter how big loop is it is adding only one button.
The loop is on rows of the sheet. Each time it should come to new row and add a button. But first time its coming to a row, adds the button and then function gets terminated. Even msgbox written after the line that adds the dynamic button does not executes.
Below is the code:

```
Public Function AddButton(strSheetName, counter)
Dim btn As OLEObject
Dim cLeft, cTop, cWidth, cHeight
    With Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("J" & (6 + counter))
        cLeft = .Left
        cTop = .Top
        cWidth = .Width
        cHeight = .Height
    End With
    With Worksheets(strSheetName)
        btn = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=cLeft, Top:=cTop, Width:=cWidth, Height:=cHeight)
    End With
    MsgBox "After Adding button"
End Function
```

Now This function is getting called in a loop. In first iteration it comes to the function adds a button to desired location and immediately after adding the button this function and the calling function(and hence the loop) gets terminated. Even the msgbox(After Adding Button) does not executes.

What may be the reason? Any help?
Thanks in advance
Akki J

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the SET Command before the `btn =` code.

Also you don't need a Function for this :) Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 5
        AddButton "Sheet1", i
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub AddButton(strSheetName As String, counter As Long)
    Dim btn As OLEObject
    Dim cLeft, cTop, cWidth, cHeight

    With Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("J" & (6 + counter))
        cLeft = .Left
        cTop = .Top
        cWidth = .Width
        cHeight = .Height
    End With
    With Worksheets(strSheetName)
        Set btn = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=True, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=cLeft, Top:=cTop, Width:=cWidth, _
        Height:=cHeight)
    End With

    MsgBox "After Adding button"
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked. You rock dude. I am new in Excel VBA. No idea at all of what is happening. Also what is this Option Explicit

Comment: Option Explicit is the "Big Brother is watching you!" ;) See this link Point 2 (http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/)